# Bidirectional communication in Distributed Objects in cocoa

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, ipc

I am new to Cocoa programming...I am learning IPC with Distributed Objects.
I have made a simple example where I am vending objects from the server and calling them in the client.I am successful in passing messages from client object to the server But I want to pass messages from server to client[Bidirectional]...How do I do that?

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification {

MYMessageServer   *server = [[MYMessageServer alloc] init];
NSConnection      *defaultConnection=[NSConnection defaultConnection];


[defaultConnection setRootObject:server];
   if ([defaultConnection registerName:@"server"] == NO)
{
    NSLog(@"Error registering server");
}
else
    NSLog(@"Connected");
[[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] configureAsServer];
}

- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification {
// Insert code here to initialize your application

//Getting an Vended Object
server = [NSConnection rootProxyForConnectionWithRegisteredName:@"server" host:nil];


if(nil == server)
{
    NSLog(@"Error: Failed to connect to server.");
}
else
{

    //setProtocolForProxy is a method of NSDistantObject
    [server setProtocolForProxy:@protocol(MYMessageServerProtocol)];
    [server addMessageClient:self];
    [server broadcastMessageString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Connected: %@ %d\n",
                                    [[NSProcessInfo processInfo] processName],
                                    [[NSProcessInfo processInfo] processIdentifier]]];
}
```

}

```
- (void)appendMessageString:(NSString *)aString
```

{

```
NSRange    appendRange = NSMakeRange([[_messageView string] length], 0);

// Append text and scroll if neccessary
[_messageView replaceCharactersInRange:appendRange withString:aString];
[_messageView scrollRangeToVisible:appendRange];
```

}

```
- (void)addMessageClient:(id)aClient
```

{

```
if(nil == _myListOfClients)
{
    _myListOfClients = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
}
[_myListOfClients addObject:aClient];
NSLog(@"Added client");
```

}

```
- (BOOL)removeMessageClient:(id)aClient
```

{

```
[_myListOfClients removeObject:aClient];
NSLog(@"Removed client");
return YES;
```

}

```
- (void)broadcastMessageString:(NSString *)aString
```

{

```
NSLog(@"Msg is %@",aString);
self.logStatement = aString;
[_myListOfClients makeObjectsPerformSelector:@selector(appendMessageString:)
                                  withObject:aString];
```

}

```
@protocol MYMessageServerProtocol
- (void)addMessageClient:(id)aClient;
- (BOOL)removeMessageClient:(id)aClient;
- (void)broadcastMessageString:(NSString *)aString;
```

Comment: The above code is working perfectly fine...I can pass messages from the client to the server....I want to pass messages from the server to the client in the same app...Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't shown the code for `MYMessageServer` or `MYMessageServerProtocol`, specifically the `-addMessageClient:` method. However, once you have passed the server a reference to an object in the client, the server can message that object like normal and that message will be sent over D.O. to the client.

So, the client is sending `self` (its application delegate) to the server via `-addMessageClient:`. The server can simply call methods on the object it receives in its implementation of `-addMessageClient:` and that will call methods on the client's application delegate object. The server can keep that reference somewhere, such as an array of clients in an instance variable, and continue to message the client at later times, too, if it wants. The server will want to clear that reference out when the connection closes, which it can detect from notifications that `NSConnection` posts.

Comment: OK, and what's wrong? You are keeping a list of the clients and sending messages to them.

Comment: @iBuilt I'd love to see this on GitHub if you ever get a chance. Meanwhile, one approach would be to do a poll technique. So, you could kick off a process with an async method (use the `(oneway void)` in the class method declaration on both client and server), and then use a sync method (one without the `oneway` keyword) to check again on the server. This is probably less code and less hairy than bidirectional?